# Does basedOn inherit visual states as well?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am creating multiple buttons with a custom template. Each button is binded to a different thumbnail image, but  I want them to all have the same visual state.  I created  **customButtonStyle** style and each other button will inherit from this style.  It seems however that the visual states are not inherited from **customButtonStyle**.

Any ideas on why it won't inherit the visuals states? and how would I set each button to its own thumbnail?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code below:

```
<Style x:Key="customButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationButtonBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="ControlRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>


                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <!--Take one half second to transition to the MouseOver state.-->
                                <VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3"/>

                                <!-- From Button Press to Normal -->
                                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlRoot">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.85"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.367" Value="1">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="3"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlRoot">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.85"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.367" Value="1">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="3"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                            <!-- Dpad focus on button-->
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlRoot">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.85"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.367" Value="1">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="3"/>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlRoot">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.85"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.367" Value="1">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="3"/>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>                      
                            <!-- Button Press-->            
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <!-- Disabled -->
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlRoot"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>            
                            <!-- End of stateGrouop -->
                        </VisualStateGroup>


                        <!-- Focus states -->
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusFill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>


                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <!-- Draw border around button that is in focus -->
                    <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!--<Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Width="208" Height="156" Source="{Binding tile1}"/>-->
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusFill" Fill="{StaticResource ApplicationButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverFill" Fill="{StaticResource ApplicationButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationButtonFocusBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="5" Margin="-2.5"/>
                    <Border x:Name="MouseOverVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Visibility="Collapsed"  BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationButtonFocusBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="5" Margin="-2.5"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

///////////////////////////

```
<Style x:Key="tile6" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource customButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                    <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Width="208" Height="156" Source="{Binding tile1}"/>            

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. As you can see for yourself, the visual states reside in the control template, and you're providing a whole new one.

You can try to place the states as resources and references them from each template, but I would advise against it. Since you have two separate templates they are likely to fork at some stage, in which reuse won't be an option. IMHO it's best to just copy them. Would make life easier in Blend as well.